# Dynamically changing the result of a zend paginator

Tags: php, zend-framework, pagination, zend-paginator

I'm struck with a Zend paginator issue for the past two days.

**My html side**

I have a form with 4 checkboxes on clicking any of these checkboxes the form will submit using jquery and based on that value Zend paginator result will occour My question is How can i submit the form when pagination links ( 1 2 3..) since it is a url

```
<form name="frm_submit" id="frm_submit" action="" method="post">
<input type="text" name="search" id="search" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="opt1" id="opt1" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="opt2" id="opt2" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="opt3" id="opt3" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="opt4" id="opt4" />
</form>

/**Controller/Action**/
 $searchdata = $this->someFun($checkboxval,$searchtextboxval); //A function returning some data based on the checkbox value
 $paginator = Zend_Paginator::factory($searchdata);
 $paginator->setItemCountPerPage(10);
 $paginator->setCurrentPageNumber($page);
 $this->view->paginator = $paginator;
```

The problem is I cant get the checkbox value in the server side when user click a pagination link(Eg 1 2 3 Next.) ? How can i do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Add attribute `value` to you input checkboxes, which holds the number of page you want to display, i.e.:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="opt1" id="opt1" value="1" />
```

2) Add the value of clicked checkboxes to the url as param:

```
URL?page=1
```

3) Retrieve page param in controller action and pass it to the paginator:

```
$params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
if (isset($params['page'])) 
    $page = $params['page'];
else 
    $page = 1;
$paginator->setCurrentPageNumber($page);
```

Comment: The value is already giving to it via jquery and its working fine..my problem is how do i get the value of checkbox when the user clicks a navigation link(Previous 1 2 3...next) etc..

Comment: I do not fully understand the logic of UI - user need to click a checkbox or a link to change the page?

Comment: Yep ..NP ...I fixed the Issue...I had to use session although i hate it